# Redirect users by the tables that they belong to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have two tables: workers_table and admins_table.

I have two controllers and I use `devise` (sign_in, sign_up...).

I use:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

in the controllers of workers and admins.

assume I have the email of the user that signed in:

```
@email = current_user.email
```

I want to check where @email is found:

- if it's found in the workers table, so redirect him to the index.html.erb of workers (and he can't enter to index.html.erb of the admins).
- if it's found in the admins table, so redirect him to the index.html.erb of admins (and he can't enter to index.html.erb of the workers).

I know how to check if the user belongs to workers_table or admins_table.

But where should I check which table the user belongs to? should I define another controller?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application_controller.rb would be a good place to define the authenticate_user functionality

another place could be a sessions_controller.rb if you have it

at the very least you could have an ensure_admin method for your admins_controller to add to the before_filter, and if they are not an admine, you could redirect_to workers#index

I'm new to rails, so i'm unsure as to the *conventional* way to do this, but the above is how I might do it.

Comment: can you explain me more where should I write the ensure_admin method? in application_controller.rb? I thought I can't create another method except for the 7 methods: create, index, destroy, show, edit, update and new.. (I'm new to rails too). thank you.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch is a good resource for authentication, and you're allowed to have whatever methods you want in controllers (although you should consider putting them in models first)